# RouteHandler conflicts with relative path

Tags: asp.net, relative-path

I have a directory structure in my project (something) similar to this one:

```
Root
  |
  |- Utilities
  |
  |- Modules
      |
      |- Admin
```

in the admin directory, I have a simple page `default.aspx` and a javascript file `validation.js`

I am just trying to refer to this file in my aspx page like

```
<script src="validation.js" ...></script>
```

since I am using route handlers, my url will be like this template

```
http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/admin/UserId/manage
```

(replace userid with a triple des encrypted string and you are set)

so since the relative path is being used to access the js file, when I try to check in firebug, its trying to access the js file with this path:

```
http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/admin/UserId/manage/validation.js
```

of course, its not present. the only way I see is to specify full relative path

```
src="\modules\admin\validation.js"
```

surely, there should be some way I can use this validation js without the full relative path. How to get that?

thanks.

ps: this is all in `.aspx` page and not codebehind (.cs)

Comment: You will need to specify the relative path. I always have a scripts folder off of the root so I use `/Scripts` or if it's in modules/admin you'll need to specify `/modules/admin` like you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem too but never been able to do anything about it. I usually end up using a full relative path and if the directory changes, well, I have to change it manually everytime. I see no other way to do this.

Of course, I would love to be proved wrong.

Comment: relative path is what is working for me now. i will use relative path only. thanks then.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the HTML `base` tag.

Specifying `<base href="http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/modules/admin/" />` in the `head` element prior to any external references will make the references take `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/modules/admin/` as the path root.  To get this functionality throughout your site, you can write a little script and include it in your master page.

I haven't tested it, but I think something like the following should would work.  :

```
    public const string BASE_HREF_FORMAT = @"<base href=""http://{0}"" />";
    public static string GetBaseHref(HttpContext httpContext){
        var sv = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var serverName = sv["SERVER_NAME"];
        var path = sv["PATH_INFO"];
        if(path.Contains("/"))
        {
            path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
        }
        return string.Format(BASE_HREF_FORMAT, path+serverName);
    }
```

You can find documentation and a tutorial at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp

Comment: but with this i still have to change it in everypage when its moved is it not?

Comment: @LocustHorde, (1) No, you just put it in the master page.  (2) What error are you getting?

Comment: ``reference.cs cannot be found (unspecified error)`` this error is i have not seen until yesterday. will master page add it to all page with proper base path with this code?

Comment: how will masterpage know what is base url for everypage? please explain?

Comment: @LocustHorde, The method I gave you takes `HttpContext` as an argument.  The `Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")` line indicates the current path.  Since the MasterPage has a reference to the page's HttpContext, this information is accessible to the master page.  Also, your error looks like you need to rebuild the solution